# How to use JSON data obtained with interface

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I am trying to create an accordion from the JSON data.

I am calling the GET request from json-server and successfully able to call the API.

I am not able to access the properties of the `children` in the variable `tileData` which shows the error:

> Property 'children' does not exist on type 'Tile[]'.

Not sure where I am going wrong.

```
tileData!: Tile[];
getTileData() {
  this.tileService.showTile().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.tileData = data;
    console.log('this.tileData.children.name :>> ', this.tileData.children.name ); //Shows error
  });
}
```

The function in service file is

```
showTile() {
  return this.http.get<Tile[]>('http://localhost:3000/data');
}
```

I have created an interface to store the obtained JSON data which is shown below:

```
export interface Tile {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  children: { name: string; image: string; url: string };
}
```

My JSON data received as follows:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "First",
      "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/football-2022-tournament-cup-background_206725-604.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Firstone",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Firsttwo",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Firstthree",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Second",
      "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/football-2022-tournament-cup-background_206725-604.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Secondone",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Secondtwo",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        },
        {
          "name": "Secondthree",
          "image": "https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hand-painted-watercolor-abstract-watercolor-background_23-2149005675.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg",
          "url": "http://www.google.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Issue 1**

Your JSON response was an object containing the `data` property with `Tile[]`.

Use [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/map) from rxjs to return as `Observable<Tile[]>`.

```js
import { map } from 'rxjs';

showTile() : Observable<Tile[]> {
  return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:3000/data')
    .pipe(map((response: any) => response.data));
}
```

**Issue 2**

While the `children` property is an array but not an object.

```js
export interface Tile {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  children: { name: string; image: string; url: string }[];
}
```

**Issue 3**

To print out the `name`, you need to iterate `titleData` and iterate `children` array from each `title` object.

```js
getTileData() {
  this.tileService.showTile().subscribe((data: any) => {
    this.tileData = data;

    for (let title of this.tileData) {
      for (let child of title.children) {
        console.log('title.children.name :>> ', child.name);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-svk87b?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned the error but, the interface definition should use exact name as you have in data.

try

```
  export interface Tile {
  name: string;
  image: string;
  children: { name: string; image: string; url: string };
}
```